# python: apply all functions inside a class to a user input

Tags: python, function, class

I have a class and a some functions that changes the user input and saves it in a file as follows.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from langdetect import detect

class Changer(object):
    def __init__ (self, sent, id):
        self.sent = sent
        self.id = id

    def panda_creator(self):
        dic = {'text': [self.sent], 'id': [self.id]}
        data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic, orient='columns')
        return data

    def remove_punc(self, data):
        data.text = data.text.str.replace('[^\w\s]', '', regex=True)
        return data

    def add_language(self, data):
        data['lang'] = data.text.apply(detect)
        return data

    def save_data(self, data):
        data.to_csv(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'file.csv'))

        
def pars(sentence, id):
    changer = Changer(sentence, id)
    changer.panda_creator()
    changer.remove_punc(changer.panda_creator())
    changer.add_language(changer.remove_punc(changer.panda_creator()))
    changer.save_data(changer.remove_punc(changer.panda_creator()))

if __name__== "__main__":
    pars(input('sentence: '), input('id: '))
```

but the parse function only returns the loader function results and not the other functions' results. and even if it did, writing the functions inside other functions would not make sense if i had more functions. so is there a way of applying all functions on the user input in this class?

for example if user-input is : sentence: please, give me a glass of water. id: 23

I would expect the output in the file.csv to be:

```
,text,id,lang
0,please give me a glass of water,23,en
```

**note: **upadte posted as the answer based on the comments given.

Comment: You could use **kwargs

Comment: hi, could you please give me a minimum example?

Comment: It sounds like what you're trying to do is to build a data processing *pipeline*.  There are many resources you could look up on how to do this in python either using existing tools or rolling your own.  That's probably what you want to search for.

Comment: "However, i get the error of missing required argument which is understandable, since I have not entered anything inside the function call in 'pars', any thoughts is welcomed." Well - what do you think should be put there? (Hint: where the code says `def remove_punc(self, data):`, where do you expect the value for `data` to come from?) Separately: I notice that you already wrote it so that `panda_creator` will call `remove_punc`, which will call the next step etc. Given this, do you think it is also necessary to call every method from outside? Why? If not, which ones? Why?

Comment: I don't think there is a useful question here; I think you just need to *think about your intended logic more carefully*. See also https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: i see your point. you are right. thank you for the hint

Comment: What issues do you have with your updated code??

Comment: thanks for reaching out, nothing at this point. other poeple's comments helped solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer based on the comments in the question.

```
class Changer(object):
    def __init__(self, sent, id):
        self.sent = sent
        self.id = id

    def panda_creator(self):
        dic = {'text': [self.sent], 'id': [self.id]}
        data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic, orient='columns')
        self.remove_punc(data)


    def remove_punc(self, data):
        data.text = data.text.str.replace('[^\w\s]', '', regex=True)
        self.add_language(data)


    def add_language(self, data):
        data['Lang_id'] = data.text.apply(detect)
        self.save_data(data)


    def save_data(self, data):
        data.to_csv(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'file.csv'))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    Changer(input('sentence: '), input('id: '))
```